# How to map domain users to a specific UID/GID in function of their domain groups?

Tags: samba, samba4

I have a samba 4.4.3 file server set up as AD domain member.

My current smb.conf file is:

```
[global]
  workgroup = MYDOMAIN
  realm = MYDOMAIN.ROOT
  security = ADS 
  encrypt passwords = yes 
  idmap config *:backend =tdb
  idmap config *:range = 70001-80000
  idmap config MYDOMAIN:backend = rid 
  idmap config MYDOMAIN:range = 80000 - 1234567890123456
  winbind trusted domains only =no 
  winbind enum users = yes 
  winbind enum groups = yes 
  domain master = no
  local master = no
  map untrusted to domain = Yes 
  dedicated keytab file = /etc/krb5.keytab
  kerberos method = secrets and keytab
  winbind refresh tickets = yes 
  dns proxy = no
  log level = 10
  max log size = 1000
  syslog = 0 
  panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
  server role = member server
  obey pam restrictions = yes 
  unix password sync = yes 
  passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
  passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
  pam password change = yes 
  map to guest = bad user
  template shell = /bin/bash
  template homedir = /home/%D/%U
  client use spnego = yes 
  read only = yes 
  create mask = 0700
  directory mask = 0700
[rw]
  path = /srv/rw
  writable = yes 
  guest ok = no
  force user = share
  force group = share
  valid users=
  allow hosts =
  deny hosts =
```

As you can see, i used "force user" and "force group" options so that every user in domain is mapped to share:share.

Now the security model changed, i would like to map a domain user to share:share **only if** the domain user is in "shareWriteAccess" (domain) group, and to ro:ro if not. Is that possible ?

The goal is to enable some domain users to have a write access on the share, while others will only have read access. I was more confident to use linux file permissions checking for that, so i thought of mapping to 2 different linux users. /srv/rw has permissions 755 share:share, so domain users mapped as ro:ro are effectively "read only". I'm open to another solution though